# Multiple categories with common subcategories

Tags: categories

In a school WP site there used to be a main category "Blog" with n subcategories for each class:

```
Blog
|__ Year 1
|__ Year 2
.
. 
|__ Year 9
```

Now we want to introduce the "Announcement" category, however this category will have the same subcategories as "Blog"

```
Announcement
|__ Year 1
|__ Year 2
.
. 
|__ Year 9
```

No big troubles since WP will create different slugs for each subcategory, however I feel like wasting subcategories and making subcategory selection a bit confusing.

I wonder if it makes sense promoting the "Year x" subcategories to main category and couple the other main categories to properly address categorising.

For instance,  a post with main categories "blog"  & "Year 2" will be related to class year 2 in the blog, while a post with main categories "announcement"  & "Year 5" will refer to an announcement for class Year 5.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is use a mixture of Categories and Tags if you prefer to prevent duplication of categories and confusion for the post authors.

Use the `Years` as `categories` and `Blog`/`Announcement` as `tag`. 
So, as example:

If they post a `Blog` for "Year 2", they post it in the `category` "Year 2" and use the `tag` "Blog".
If they post an `Announcement` for "Year 5", they post it in the `category` "Year 5" and use the tag `Announcement`

In your menu structure you can use a individual link / custom link with the following structure:

```
/%category%/?tag=%tag%
```

Examples:

```
Blog:     /?tag=blog
-Year 1:  /year-1/?tag=blog
-Year 2:  /year-2/?tag=blog
-Year 3:  /year-3/?tag=blog
...
```

and

```
Announcements: /?tag=announcement
-Year 1:       /year-1/?tag=announcement
-Year 2:       /year-2/?tag=announcement
-Year 3:       /year-3/?tag=announcement
...
```

Surely it depends on your permalink structure, so it could be like:

```
-Year 1:       /categorie/year-1/?tag=announcement
```

or

```
-Year 2:       /cat/year-2/?tag=announcement
```

or whatever your structure is.

### ------------------------------------------------------------

Otherwise you can create for every category-mix like
Blog & Year 1, Blog & Year 2, Announcement & Year 1, Announcement & Year 2 ... a custom template file with a query calling these two categories loading into a page so you can set the page as your menu item.

Read more about queries here:

- [Query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)
- [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: I see that users are a bit confused about using tags and most-of-all they may use tags misspelling and creating wrong ones. Although your idea of creating a mix of categories and tags seems better from an architectural point of view, I am afraid it can lead into troubles for the users. Maybe I would prefer using mixed categories although I have to plan in advance theme-related potential problems, for instance dealing with category pages... what happens when a user will click on a class category? All posts related to that category (blog or announcement) will mix together?

Comment: Yes, they would be all mixed together if you use the Class/Year as main Category. This would be actually not a problem, as example, if my kid goes to Class 4 I wouldn't mind to have a overview of all actual informations being posted regarding that class and still can filter it through sub-categories (Blog/Announcements). You could implant a sub-menu into each individual template for the users to filter Blogs and Announcements.

Comment: In this case I could develop custom category pages to list posts not just from one but from two categories, for example blog+class or announcement+class. This should help filtering a bit contents. So the site could have: category-announcement list (announcements for all classes), category-blog list (blogs from all classes) or announcement+class/blog+class to filter contents for a specific class.  Of course  this would not prevent users from clicking on a category-class forwarding them to an overview as you wrote. Seems to be acceptable?

Comment: Seems very reasonable and acceptable. Might be the best way if you don't want the post creators to get confused by tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating my first blog and have the same issue: 3 categories (history culture and politics) with the same subcategories (different European countries A, B, C...). How can I organise my menu items?
Would it be appropriate to have it like this:

### Countries:

### -B

.
.
.
And then a hover over each country shows the three categories:

A:
-History
-Culture
-Politics

B:
-History
-Culture
-Politics

C:
.
.
.